# In Java, why is the class "Arrays" plural?

Tags: java, arrays

In Java, you `import HashMap;` and `import ArrayList;`, etc. So why is `import Arrays;` plural?

Comment: Do you mean "import java.util.Arrays;" ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about choices made by the JVM authors

Comment: To make it uniquely named.  There are _two_ "List" classes in the JRE, which mean you always have to explitlity mention which one you want.

Comment: that's a built-in class, from java.util.* package used to manipulate array, like Arrays.binarySearch (..)

Comment: @RC Whats wrong about understanding the choices of the JVM authors? After all they affect Java developers life daily. And if you understand them you can much better navigate the JCL.

Comment: @eckes probably nothing, but I don't see how the SO crowd could explain "choices"

Comment: @RC I think we even have a lot of OpenJDK and Oracle contributors here. But yes you are right, the answers are most likely more or less guesses. Still interesting ones.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Utility classes which deals with `Arrays`, [`Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html), [`Paths`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html), [`Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) or [`Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) are plural. Exactly because they are not an Array or a Collection but rather a number of utility functions to work on them. You can even see that in the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) intro:

> This class contains various methods for manipulating arrays

Some of those classes are fairly new additions in 1.7. So this explains their common naming convention. I am not sure if there is a written conventions for it, but it is surely a practical one.

Comment: Removed StandardCharsets and added Paths. FilesSystems is a bit more like StandardCharsets.

Answer (score 4):

Because it's a collection of utilities to work with arrays. The other examples you've mentioned are actually instances of a particular type of collection.

For example, the same naming convention has been followed in Guava for Lists, Sets, Maps etc.

Answer (score 4):

It is a collection of utilities that deals with arrays, and doesn't represent the array itself. Also there is another class with name `Array`. Check this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html

Answer (score 2):

HashMap, ArrayList, etc are objects. They are data structures which offer different features and have different uses.

[Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html) (or [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)) on the other hand is *not* an object. Arrays is a class which features only static utility methods that can perform convenient operations on arrays.

Answer (score 2):

It's up to author and code conversions how to name classes.

Comment: somehow this is the correct answer XD

Comment: Right, but wanting to understand why things are named a certain way is normal; it helps developers to reason about their tools. And assuming you meant to say 'code conventions,' the asker showed multiple examples of how this is not in convention with other class names.